# ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job. Finished: FAILURE

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, jenkins, tomcat

i am deploying a jar file of java project through git repository in aws centos 7 by installing maven

```
Started by user sudeep garg
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test1
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/buildpacks/sample-java-app.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/buildpacks/sample-java-app.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 1.8.3.1'
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/buildpacks/sample-java-app.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please could you post the Jenkins code too. This bit looks very odd /master^{commit}

Comment: I happen to see the same in my Jenkins MultiBranch Plugin where I am trying to build PR pipeline and it error out due to the exact same issue.

Comment: I am not sure what's the issue ```ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.``` And I confirm the revision aka last commit should be built

Answer (score 0):

The default branch for the repo https://github.com/buildpacks/sample-java-app is

```
main
```

you are trying to checkout

```
master
```

Set this to main and it should work.